# Understanding "this" in Backbone / Javascript

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to understand how to create objects and methods with Backbone.  I started with something like this:

```
Person = (function () {
  return Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
      name: 'jon' 
    },

    changeName: function (newName) {
     console.log(newName);
      this.name = newName;
    }
  });

})();


var p1 = new Person();
console.log(p1.get('name'));
p1.changeName("samanatha");
console.log(p1.get('name'));
```

What I don't understand is, why doesn't my p1.name property change.  I thought it had something to do with "this" in this.name since I'm still trying to grasp how 'this' works, but I think I'm missing something else since `this.name = newName` and `name=newName` both do not work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`name` is contained in the attributes of your model: `p1.attributes.name`. That's why you access it using `get()`. If you want to change `name`, you can do one of the following:

```
p1.set("name", "samantha")

p1.set({"name": "samantha"})
```

By passing in an object, the latter allows you to set multiple attributes at once.

According to the [docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-attributes):

```
Please use set to update the attributes instead of modifying them directly.
```

This is so Backbone can do things like trigger a `change` event when you change an attribute, or provide a serialized version of the attributes when you call `toJSON()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
...
changeName: function (newName) {
 console.log(newName);
  this.name = newName;
}
...
```

Should be

```
...
changeName: function (newName) {
 console.log(newName);
  this.set ({'name': newName});
}
...
```

http://backbonejs.org/#Model-set